# Rubocop RSpec Describes are failing

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubocop

Actually i'm trying to fix that issues:

> Do not use multiple top level describes - try to nest them.
>
> The first argument to describe should be the class or module being tested.

I have eight tests in that format:

```
describe 'PublicanCreatorsCreate.init_docu_work' do
  it 'accesses a directory and creates there an initial documentation' do
    PublicanCreatorsCreate.init_docu_work(title, type, language, brand, db5)
    Dir.exist?(title)
    :should == true
  end
end
```

But what is false? The first argument contains the tested class and method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally such a describe would be written as:

```
describe PublicanCreatorsCreate, '.init_docu_work' do
```

or

```
describe PublicanCreatorsCreate do
  describe '.init_docu_work' do
```

It sounds like [rubocop-rspec](https://github.com/nevir/rubocop-rspec) is expecting the second form.